# Comparing XML elements in JUnit

Tags: xml, junit

JUnit class which tries to compare the XML input with the XML output fails.

```
TestCase.assertEquals(msg, expected, actual);
```

Is there any way to compare XML i/p & o/p from JUnit?

Answer (score 6):

You could look at [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/). This allows you to compare two XML documents. From the docs:

> XMLUnit enables JUnit-style assertions to be made about the content
>   and structure of XML. It is an open source project hosted at
>   http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ that grew out of a need to test a
>   system that generated and received custom XML messages. The problem
>   that we faced was how to verify that the system generated the correct
>   message from a known set of inputs. Obviously we could use a DTD or a
>   schema to validate the message output, but this approach wouldn't
>   allow us to distinguish between valid XML with correct content (e.g.
>   element bar) and valid XML with incorrect content (e.g.
>   element baz). What we really wanted was an assertXMLEqual()
>   method, so we could compare the message that we expected the system to
>   generate and the message that the system actually generated.